# Rename a file when I don't know its name - shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to rename a file which is the only file in a directory.

It is a podcast download which changes name each day so I don't know what it is called but it always ends in .MP3

I want to rename it to news.mp3

I have tried the following based on another solution on this site but it  appends the news to the file

```
 #!/bin/sh
for file in *.MP3; do
    mv "$file" "${file/.MP3/news.mp3}"
done
```

Comment: Will there ever be more than one MP3 in the directory?

Comment: First you need to find the latest mp3 file, then rename it

Comment: Say that the name of the file is `foo.MP3`. You then rename it to `foonews.mp3` in the same directory. There is no appending going on. But be careful about capitalization: There are platforms (cygwin comes to my mind) which, due to limitations of the operating system, can't distinguish consistently between upper and lower case in filenames. If you run the script again on such a platform, it would pick up the new file foonews.mp3 and rename it to foonewsnews.mp3. I suggest that you run your script with `-x` turned on to verify what's happening.

Comment: Other minor note: You didn't post how you invoke your script, but from the #! line of the script, it is not a bash program, and I wondered why you tagged this question as _bash_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the only file in the directory you can just write the following command:

```
mv directory_name/* directory_name/news.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there are few files or if dir is empty:

```
shopt -s nullglob
src="/path/to/dir/with/files"
dst="/destanation/folder"
i=1
cd "$src"
for f in *; do
   mv "$f" "$dst/new_name_$((i++))"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you have multiple files in the directory but you partially know the name of the file you want to change and its unique to the directory.  Here's an example called `mything-1.1.2.deb`:

```
mv $(ls mything*) mything.deb
```